# Custom MessageBox with custom-defined Buttons

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance, button, messagebox

I've got a project that uses a `ListBox` containing the paths of image files (these appear depending on search criteria).
What I'm trying to implement now is that, when a listbox item is selected, a MessageBox-style form appears giving the user the option to view the image in a `PictureBox` on the application or view full-screen (using Process.Start()). I'd like to give these options using separate buttons, but obviously a `MessageBox` can only be created using default buttons.

I've had a look at doing this using a Class that inherits `MessageBox`, but passing any values to the `base` constructor gives an error message.

Is there a way around this, or is there a better way to basically imitate the `MessageBox` and essentially replace the buttons?

Comment: I had this in the past, you can implement your own custom MessageBox by simply creating a form with buttons that you need and without maximise/minimize controls.

Comment: showing a MessageBox on each selection can quickly become annoying for users. i suggest to show a preview of image in pictureBox on item selection and open a full-screen view on item double-click or pictureBox double-click